# Team Foundation Server - Move project to a new collection?

Tags: tfs

I have a project that is in the default collection on my TFS server. Is it possible to move the project from this collection to a new one that I created? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The project exists within the Collection Database, you can't just pickup and move a Team Project out of a database.

There is a [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) that can copy Team Projects between services.

Generally it's best to [plan](http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/) this sort of stuff upfront as to avoid issues like this down the line. I have heard rumours Microsoft are working on improving this, but I don't think anything will be available for a while.